# Errors while compiling 99 bottles code in java

Tags: java, compilation

I am a novice programmer in Java (or atleast trying to be one) and I am having some issues with my code.

Its a song called 99 beers of bottles where it goes from 99 to 0 and then it stops. The code :

```
public class 99bottles {

public static void main (String[] args) {

    String word = "bottles";
    x bottle = 99;

    for (int i==0; i<99; i--) {
        if (i == 1) {
            word = "bottle";
        }

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(i+ "Bottles of beer on the wall, " + i + " bottles of beer.");

        int y = i - 1 ;
        System.out.println("Take one down and pass it around, " + y + " bottles of beer on the wall.");



    }
}
```

}

However as soon as I try compiling it, I get errors that seem illogical.
Here 
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/moTJ7.png)

I was busting my head against the wall before deciding to go here for help.

Comment: check the part `i==0` is it meant to be  a comparison  ?

Comment: `x bottle = 99;` <-- what is this?

Comment: also check what  are the valid java identifier names like `class 99bottles`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of changes to your code required:

You can remove:

```
x bottle = 99;
```

Your loop should be something like `for (int i = 99; i > 0; i--) {`

And pass the variable into the `println` statement:

```
System.out.println(i + " " + word + " of beer on the wall, " + i + " " + word + " of beer.");
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot of syntax errors in your code:

- class name can't start with a number
- `x` doesn't seem to be a valid type: `x bottle = 99;`
- wrong condition in `for` loop: `int i==0`

And also semantic errors:

- `for (int i==0; i<99; i--)` - decrementing from 0 and checking if less than 99, it is an infinite loop

Comment: Thank you very much. I cannot believe I was so blind for things like these. However I knew my for loop was wrong just didnt know why. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Two changes(Haven't checked logic of your code):

1) `x bottle = 99;` to `int bottle = 99;`

2) `for (int i==0; i<99; i--)` to `for (int i=0; i<99; i--)`

`==` means comparison and `=` is used to assign value

`x bottle = 99` to define a variable you need to use type.

***EDIT:***

Class name can't start with number

Answer (score 0):

Here is a cleaned up version of what you were trying to do:

```
for (int i = 99; i > 0; i--) {
    String bottle = "bottle" + i > 1 ? "s" : "";
    System.out.println(i + bottle + " of beer on the wall, " + i + bottle + " of beer.");
    System.out.println("Take one down and pass it around, " + y + bottle + " of beer on the wall.");
}
```

Your current code is rife with problems, including:

- class names cannot start with a number
- `i == 0` does not assign a value to the loop counter, it compares it; instead use `i = 0`
- `x bottle = 99;` this appears to just be dead dangling code, and your code should not even be compiling right now
- you did correctly pick up on the edge case of the word `bottle` needing to be singular when the count reaches one; but you never fully implemented it, q.v. the above code snippet for one possible way to do that

Comment: Thanks for the cleaned up version. I will take a deep look at it.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the working code for your purpose:(just copy and use!)**

```
public static void main (String[] args) {

    String word = "bottles";
   // x bottle = 99;

    for (int i=0; i<=99; i++) {
        if (i == 1) {
            word = "bottle";
        }

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println((99-i)+ " Bottles of beer on the wall, " + (99-i) + " bottles of beer.");

        int y =99 - 1 ;
        System.out.println("Take one down and pass it around, " + y + " bottles of beer on the wall.");



    }
}
```

Comment: While this might give an answer, you should probably explain the changes instead of giving just a full code dump. OP needs to learn :)

Answer (score 0):

Luke gave a very good [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46824483/6722100), please check the loop condition carefully.

`for (int i = 0 ; i < 99 ; i--)` means you start with an integer '0', then you keep decrementing 0 by 1 until `i` is not less than 99. However if you keep reducing the 0, you will always get a number which is less than 99, hence your closing condition will never be fulfilled.

Two alternatives that you can do:

`for (int i = 0; i < 99 ; i++)`

or

```
for (int i = 99; i > 0 ; i--)
```

This is mostly a syntax or a semantic related error as Luke said.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that for me!